# Problemas al intentar registrar información en el formulario HTML a mi base de datos con XAMPP

Tags: javascript, php, html, xampp

Llevo varios días intentando conectar mi base de datos MySQL en XAMPP con mi formulario html, y me sale error 405 Y Unexpected end of JSON input. Supuestamente debía configurar el servidor web XAMPP para que aceptara el método POST, y aún así me sigue saliendo el mismo error 405, he estado usando IA para que me ayude a solucionar pero por mas que sigo las instrucciones para solucionar los problemas con este método no se solucionan:

### HTML:

```
<form id="register-form" action="guardar_registro.php" method="POST">
```

### JavaScript:

```
fetch('/banderas 4/guardar_registro.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      nombreUsuario: nombreUsuario,
      correoElectronico: correoElectronico,
      contraseña: contraseña
    })
  })
```

#### PHP:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST")
```

Comment: Hola. ¿Puedes explicar lo que has hecho para autorizar el método `POST`?

Comment: Hola, primero en el código php: if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST" se establece el método post. Segundo en la carpeta httpd accediendo desde XAMPP configuré el servidor para que me acepte todos los métodos incluyendo el POST:  <Directory "C:/Users/echav/OneDrive/Escritorio/NUEVOO/banderas 4">
    Require all granted
</Directory>. he probado de todo :c

Comment: En ninguno de los dos casos que mencionas estarías autorizando al método POST. Con el `if` sólo verificas si la petición es del tipo POST y lo que haces en `Directory` no es correcto y podría ser hasta peligroso. ¿Podrías mostrar lo que tienes en el archivo de configuración de Apache y decirnos además qué versión de Apache tienes instalada?

Comment: he usado todo lo que me recomienda la IA o veo en youtube, me dierón dos supuestos parametros para permitir el método POST, por una lado dentro del ´codigo PHP agregue al principio(header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");) y tampoco sirvió, tambin configurpe el servidor httpd con los parametros que ya mostré. La versión de XAMPP en mi ordenador es la V3.3.0.

Comment: esto es lo que hay dentro del configurable del sevidor: <Directory "C:/Users/echav/OneDrive/Escritorio/NUEVOO/banderas 4">
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Comment: No me refiero a tu versión de XAMPP, sino a tu versión de Apache, que no es lo mismo. La última versión de Apache es `2.4`. Si tienes una versión `2.3`o superior, para permitir el método POST tendrías que usar [`AllowMethods`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_allowmethods.html) poniendo algo como esto: **`<Location "/"> AllowMethods GET POST </Location>`** Ahí estás permitiendo también `GET` y debes poner todos aquellos métodos que quieres permitir. En versiones anteriores tienes que usar algo como esto: **`<Limit POST GET> Require valid-user </Limit>`**.

Comment: No tenía el apache instalado -,-, estoy inslatando la ultima versión 2.4.46, aunque pregunto a chat gpt y me dice que esto no solucionara el problema.

Comment: Me descargue httpd-2.4.46-o111i-x64-vc15 y entro en el archivo configurable del servidor httpd y me salen los valores de dicha carpeta con los valores como por defecto como: <Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

Comment: ¿Y sigue dando el mismo error?

Comment: Desafortunadamente si :c

Comment: ¿Y las otras URLs funcionan sin problema, sólo te falla si intentas mandar un formulario o algo así? Revisa el `.htaccess` de la carpeta donde tienes el archivo `guardar_registro.php` y también dentro del directorio root.